# Guice - How to provide an API supporting flexible pluggable strategy implementations with their own bindings?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, strategy-pattern

We are designing an API which allows clients to provide a number of pluggable strategies (specific implementations of a strategy interface) to constitute an individual instance of an application. In addition, we would preferably like for these to be defined in the instance's configuration file to allow them to be changable without the need for a new build.

In order to make our API easily testable and maintainable moving forward we are using Guice as our DI framework. The aforementioned strategies will therefore be bound via the Multibinder extension, since there can be any number of implementations for a given instance of the application. Each strategy has an identifier associated with it so it is added to a mapbinder which maps strategy identifier -> strategy implementation class.

The issue we are having with this approach is that these strategies may themselves utilise the strategy pattern. You could therefore have these strategies being instances of the same class but with different dependency implementations injected. The strategies can be left to configure their own bindings but this will lead to them attempting to bind different implementations of the same interface (I think this is similar to the robot legs problem?)

To take a simple example, say our API was dependent on `HelloWorld` strategies defined in configuration and these were implementations of the following interface.

```
public interface HelloWorldStrategy {
    public String getMessage(String caller);
}
```

In our "pluggable" code we have the following implementations.

```
public class HelloWorld implements HelloWorldStrategy {
    public String getMessage(String caller) { return "Hello World"; }
}

public class HelloCountry implements HelloWorldStrategy {
    private final CountryStrategy countryStrategy;

    @Inject
    public HelloCountry(CountryStrategy countryStrategy) {
        this.countryStrategy = countryStrategy;
    }

    public String getMessage(String caller) { 
        return "Hello " + countryStrategy.getCountry(String caller);
    }
}
```

In our configuration file we may want to define multiple instance of the `HelloCountry` class but which have different bindings for the `CountryStrategy` interface. Therefore, the approach we considered is to allow for the Module instances themselves to be specified in configuration. However, in this approach you would get collisions when the two different modules attempt to bind different implementations to the `CountryStrategy` interface.

The approach we are thinking of taking is to provide client developers with the assurance that the modules they write which bind the strategy implementations are isolated. We do this by having a setup module which creates a separate injector for each module which binds one of these implementations of `HelloWorldStrategy`. For the example above, this would look something like the below.

```
public class HelloWorldStrategySetupModule extends AbstractModule {

private final List<HelloWorldStrategyModule> strategyModules;
private final Injector parentInjector;

public HelloWorldStrategySetupModule(List<HelloWorldStrategyModule> strategyModules, Injector parentInjector) {
    this.strategyModules = strategyModules;
    this.parentInjector = parentInjector;
}

@Override
protected void configure() {
    MapBinder<String, HelloWorldStrategy> mapbinder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, HelloWorldStrategy.class);

    for(HelloWorldStrategyModule strategyModule : strategyModules) {
        Injector strategyModuleInjector = parentInjector.createChildInjector(strategyModule);
        mapbinder.addBinding(strategyModule.getIdentifier()).toInstance(strategyModuleInjector.getInstance(HelloWorldStrategy.class));
    }
}
```

Where an example of a strategy module (defined in config) would be:

```
public class EuropeanCountryStrategyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        binder().bind(CountryStrategy.class).to(EuropeanCountriesStrategy.class);
        binder().bind(HelloWorldStrategy.class).to(HelloCountry.class);
    }
}
```

This works but seems a little overkill for what we're trying to achieve, which is effectively attempting to incorporate a configuration-based strategy pattern. Has anyone come across a similar problem or have any best-practice ways to solve these problems?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks for reading if you got this far.

Answer (score -1):

I've solved the same issue by passing an org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration instance to my module. I load this configuration in the main of my application.

```
public class FlywheelModule extends AbstractModule
{

private Configuration topologyConfig;

public FlywheelModule(Configuration topologyConfig)
{
    this.topologyConfig = topologyConfig;
}
...
```

and then just parsing from the configure method:

```
if (topologyConfig.getString("topology.instanceConfiguration.persistence[@type]").equalsIgnoreCase("XML"))
    {
        bind(InstanceConfigurationPersistenceStrategy.class).to(XmlInstanceConfigurationPersistenceStrategy.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(InstanceConfiguration.class).toProvider(InstanceConfigurationProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
    else
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I think the issue we have is slightly different. Our API needs to load these strategies at runtime without any knowledge of their own implementations or internal dependencies (or indeed how many of them there will be). Therefore, if two strategies have the same implementing class but different internal bindings then you could have collisions without using a separate injector. This isn't clear from the question title so I've amended it slightly.

Comment: you could bind each strategy to instance (and instanciate the objects according to configuration): bind(Service.class).toInstance(new ServiceImpl("some parameters));bind(Service.class).toInstance(new ServiceImpl("some different parameters));